# Events on EditText not fired at all

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an EditText and I want to catch the event when the user is using "Done" or "Enter". Currently, I'm testing on an emulator with Pixel API 26

I've tried many solutions found on StackOverFlow such as adding setSingleLine or editing the XML with

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:inputType="text"
android:maxLines="1""
```

and nothing works. I really don't know what is the problem.

This is the XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ic_magnify"
    android:background="@null"
    android:hint="Enter Address, City or Zip Code"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo|actionSearch|actionNext|actionSend"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

In my MapFragment class, I'm obtaining the reference to the EditBox inside the "onCreateView" function:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container,
                false);

    mSearchText = v.findViewById(R.id.input_search);
    mSearchText.setSingleLine();
    init();

    // Hiding the action bar
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

    return v;
}
```

and then in the "init" function, I'm doing this:

```
private void init() {

    Log.d("Yolo2", "Before");

    //Search field
    mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    Log.d("Yolo2", "Yes");
                    //execute our method for searching
                    geoLocate();
                }

            Log.d("Yolo2", "No");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried many other events and none of them worked. I'm getting nothing from the debug logs. I've tried on key change events to catch and key typed inside the EditText.

Comment: have you tried using textWatchers ?, I believe your requirements will work better with using those.

Comment: Try leaving only one action option`android:imeOptions="actionDone"` or `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` but then don't forget to add `android:nextFocusForward="@+id/your_next_focused_view"`

Comment: Can you link to some of the solutions that didn't work, so we know what not to suggest as answers?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWowf5SkiOE
Which leads to the source code here: https://github.com/mitchtabian/Google-Maps-Google-Places/tree/99301af3e4bcb0ecc9b87da121af1b7fb7b17b8c

Besides that I've a few solutions such as:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498009/handle-edittext-key-change-event-with-input-type-text
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063439/android-edittext-finished-typing-event

and many more.

Comment: @Umair I've tried it but didn't work also.

I really don't know what's going on. Maybe the problem is with something else?

Comment: @DmitriiLeonov I've also tried your solution with no success.

Comment: @Ondskan maybe you didn't implemented it correctly :). Can you share your that piece of code ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't share the whole project. If there is any missing code that might be related let me know and I will share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me with this issue.
I've made a mistake by using this code in the MapFragment class when I should have used it on the MapActivity. My code works now just fine and all your answers are probably correct too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your if condition and give try

```
 mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            geoLocate();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried it but still, nothing happens. I've added a log before the 'geoLocate();' also.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` and check with below code. First handle `KeyEvent` and then `action`.

```
mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent != null && keyEvent.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return false;

        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
            || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                Log.d("Yolo2", "Yes");
                //execute our method for searching
                geoLocate();
        }

        Log.d("Yolo2", "No");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Same as before. No log and nothing happens when I'm trying to breakpoint on the 'If' statements.

Comment: `mSearchText` really attach to `input_search`? Could you please add more details?

Comment: `        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container,
                false);

        mSearchText = v.findViewById(R.id.input_search); '

I don't know how to write code in the comments here so I've added the entire 'OnCreateView' function to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
    mSearchText = v.findViewById(R.id.input_search);
mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            geoLocate();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure you use `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` or only one imeOptions in xml at a time and replace the same in java code. It will definitely work.